# Copying Tridion SmartTarget Promotions between environments

Tags: smarttarget

I have separate environments for SmartTarget (Dev, Test & Prod).

After I make a change in Dev (updating the Component Id of an existing promotion), how can I replicate/copy this same change into the other environments? Does it have to be done manually?

Comment: Hi User, welcome to the forum could you please give some more information regarding which version of Tridion you are using and which version of SmartTarget you are using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, as you have separate SmartTarget installations for Dev, Test, Prod, etc., there is (currently) no way of 'Content Porting' changes made to a Promotion in one environment into another - **You will have to move these manually.**

You can use the `Copy to` functionality within SmartTarget 2014 (and later) to copy Promotions between different Targets (e.g. Staging and Live), but not between environments as you require. More details on copying Promotions can be found in the [SDL LiveContent documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-119DBB77-D0DB-4D59-BD2F-29C6D0DBA8E1) (login required).

Moving them manually also ensures that all of the `Triggers` that you are using are available in the target environment, and allows you to check that any IDs you are using are actually present too.